# How to cover a floor with a bitmap in Autodesk Revit

Tags: revit-api

I want to cover a floor in Autodesk Revit with an external bitmap (e.g. png file). The texture should be visible in both 2D and 3D view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skgzL.png)

Comment: I think it is more productive to specify what you already tried, and what are the difficulties that have prevented you from doing it yourself.

Comment: First of all I would like to know if this is possible, if so, do I have to program an add-in?

Comment: In order to know whether you can program an add-in to solve this, you should first determine the possibility, optimal workflow and best practices to achieve it manually through the user interface. The Revit API hardly ever supports any functionality that is not available (and easier to research) in the user interface first, cf. [How to research to find a Revit API solution](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#3).